# What's the equivalent of FindResource for finding a resource by control type?

Tags: wpf

I want to do `FindResource("{x:Type TextBox}")` or `FindResource(GetType(TextBox))` and get a `Style` object back?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find an implicit `Style` (without an `x:Key`):

```
Style style = FindResource(typeof(Button)) as Style;
```

...that is defined in your XAML markup like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
</Style>
```

In VB.NET the corresponding code would be:

```
Dim style As Style = TryCast(FindResource(GetType(Button)), Style)
```